# Java Mail Exception error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Error Stack trace -

```
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at Report.sendmail(Report.java:100)
    at Report.main(Report.java:301)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
```

Code -

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
         properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "172.16.200.60");
         properties. put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
         properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtpserver");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
         properties.put("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
         "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");


         Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
         try{
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
             String[] toAddress = toemailAddress.toArray(new String[toemailAddress.size()]);
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toAddress).replace("[", "") .replace("]", "").replace(",",","));
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                     InternetAddress.parse(Arrays.toString(toAddress).replace("[", "") .replace("]", "").replace(" ","")));
             String[] ccAddress = ccemailAddress.toArray(new String[ccemailAddress.size()]);

             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, 
                     InternetAddress.parse(Arrays.toString(ccAddress).replace("[", "") .replace("]", "")));
             message.setSubject(subject);

             MimeBodyPart  messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
             String body ="Please find attached Shipping documents for Transfer Order '"+xoNumber+"'.";
             messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");

             Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

             for (String filename : filesfromFolders){
                        MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                        attachPart.attachFile(filename);
                        multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
             }

             message.setContent(multipart);
             Transport.send(message);
             System.out.println("Email sent  successfully to ");




         }
         catch (Exception mex) {
              mex.printStackTrace();
          }
```

I Have done following things

1. Adding properties to trust host
2. stop IPV4 but doesn't works.
3. I converted java 7 to java 6 but no use
4. Open port 25 but doesnt works
5. Ip address is working telnet command

but doesn't works

Comment: Are you able to telnet on port 25 too?

Comment: ...and you're ***positive*** that the IP address is live and valid?  (Also, I hope for your sake that it isn't a real IP.)

Comment: Yes I can able to telnet

Comment: _"Network is unreachable"_ is a very low-level message indicating there's no route to the remote host.  Please edit your post and show (copy/paste) the result of the commands `telnet 172.16.200.60 25` and `traceroute 172.16.200.60` (on Windows use `tracert 172.16.200.60`)

Comment: Once you figure out your networking problem, you can clean up your code by fixing these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Note also that it's very unlikely your mail server is using SSL on port 25.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the 172.16.200.60 address is reported unreachable by the network layer.

I would suggest you reverify that "telnet 172.16.200.60 25" works.  If not, you need to fix your network configuration (TCP/IP routing, DHCP server).

If telnet works, I would suggest you look into whether your JVM is configured to use a proxy of any kind outside of the source shown, because then the error can be reported if the proxy is unreachable.